# Yet another intuition question on surface integrals?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

This may seem a basic question about surface integrals, but I'm reading Div, Grad, Curl, and All That, and it prompted me some soul-searching.

In most textbooks, they start discussion of a surface integral by saying take a small patch, $S$, of the surface and imagine a force acting through it.

This force acts at some angle relative to the normal vector, as the book illustrations invariably show.

Then, say the books, the formula for the flux of that small area, $S$, is the dot product of the Force and the Normal vector. And of course as $S$ gets infinitesimally small, integration becomes the solution.

So my intuition question, and apologies for the elementary nature of this. Is the reason you take the dot product of the normal and the force because we are projecting the force on to the normal? And is this because the actual force acting on $S$ is not F itself, since it is an angle (kind of like the incline plane problem in basic physics) to the normal, but the projection of F onto N?

In other words: in a simple incline plane problem, the force of someone pulling up the hill has a vertical and a horizontal component, and to find the amount of force in the horizontal direction you can take the projection of F onto the horizontal plane (right?). So in the case of a surface integral, the force in the normal direction, which I am really interested in, is the dot product of F and the normal vector. And that is why you integrate F dot N ds in surface integrals. And, as the vertical force in an inclined plane problem is a bit of a "waste," so, too, flux will be less the greater the angle between the force and the normal vector.

How wrong is that?

Comment: I think your intuition is correct. The dot product is indeed used to project the vector field $\vec F$ onto the normal vector $\vec n$ in order to get the component of $\vec F$ acting in the same direction as $\vec n$. See the third illustration under ["Surface integrals of vector fields"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_vector_fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the main point in the physical interpretation here. We're finding the *flux* of the vector field across the surface. We want to find the (rate of) fluid flow of $\vec F$ *across* the surface (think of $\vec F$ as some variant of a velocity vector field of the fluid). Fluid that flows tangent to the surface contributes no flux. Thus, we want the normal component of $\vec F$, multiplied by area, to figure out how much fluid goes across. (If it helps, see part of my [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNy0ehstWBc&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd&index=92&t=11s). There is a small glitch, unfortunately, in the discussion, which I did correct a few minutes later.)

Comment: Just watched. Very helpful, and your whole series looks great!

Comment: a question from your video. You talked about flux as the rate of fluid flow and helpfully draw a parallelopiped that shows the amount of fluid that would go through a designated surface area. In your diagram, the parallelopiped was at a certain angle to the surface, reflecting the angle that F itself was hitting the surface.

Comment: But you then added that we use the F * normal *ds because you are interested in the volume of your notional parallelopiped (I think that is a fair summary). You talk about "shear." I'm not familiar with that idea.  is the area of the parallelopiped the surface area (yes) times the normal?

Comment: Rather, a mistake in the earlier comment. Is the volume of the parallelepiped the surface area of the top (yes) times the height (yes), and the height is the normal vector (hmmm)?

Comment: The height is precisely $\vec F\cdot\vec n$.

Comment: Then that explanation on the video is the best I've seen after much searching. Very very helpful. Many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. You might even decide to learn differential forms :D You should definitely watch the Gauss's Law and falling through the earth video.  P.S. You can accept this answer and post a new question when you have one :)

Comment: Yes, I should do that. I'm just 15 though, and making my way through mv calculus :(. If I post another full question, asking for a geometric demonstration that the height of a sheared parallelepiped involves the normal vector, would you answer that at your convenience? You say, in minute 15, that a sheared parallelepiped has a height of, I think, displacement times the normal. But that's not obvious to me.

Comment: It's just base times height. If you fix the base of a triangle and slide the upper vertex along a line parallel to it, all the triangles you get have the same area. Same thing in 3D, fixing the base and varying the upper vertex parallel to it. (Sliding it parallel to the base is the "shear" to which I referred.) You might actually enjoy going back to the beginning of the lectures and learning the basic linear algebra.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I should on that linear algebra!